# About Adding Sim slot on Lg optimus Exceed 2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My cousin presented me a new Lg optimus Exceed 2 from Us and i was in India..there is no sim slot for this mobile..i need to insert any sim to this mobile.?please help me..

Thank you,

Ajay

Answer (score 2):

According to [PDAdb](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=6000&c=lg_vs450pp_optimus_exceed_2), the phone is Verizon-exclusive and CDMA-only, hence it doesn't have a SIM slot (the store programs the cell info into the phone on purchase).

That is, even if you somehow manage to open a hole in the mid-frame, solder a SIM slot on it, *and* persuade the OS into accepting it, you still will not be able to use it because there's no GSM support at all.